# Dev site with no traffic got 11 millions queries in just 4 days??

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

We moved to AWS because we thought Amazon must be doing a good business practice. We don't expect something cunning here. However, it really doesn't make sense for us to get 11 millions DNS queries in 4 days for a site that is not even alive yet. Who is doing that?

FYI: All TTLs are already set to 86400 (except the NS record which is 172800).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about guessing who might be hitting your server, with no information whatsoever.

Comment: I apologize. If you want me to delete, I can delete it. However, from the access log, all I see are only bingbot, googlebot and ourselves. That's why we see something weird here. Not sure what other information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question says that you are getting 11 million DNS queries. Is it possible that you are the target of a DNS amplification attack and your server is being used to stage attack?

Take a look at https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA13-088A. Make sure your DNS server is secure against recursive lookups.

The other possibility is that the server you were on was previously used to stage a DNS amplification attack. If this is the case, I would terminate and recreate your EC2 instance on another node if you need to host a DNS server.

Comment: We're using Amazon Route 53. I believe they're secure enough, but I'm not sure though. I've tried to create a new instance. Unfortunately, I can only create in the same AZ since I've just paid the Reserved Instance in that specific AZ, thus can't be changed to other AZ.

Comment: It seems that Route 53 is not secure enough against illegitimate recursive look ups. Anyway, I solved it by contacting the guys who attacking my domain.